# iOS camera roll video with phonegap?

Tags: ios, api, cordova, video, camera

Now that Mobile Safari on iOS 6 supports capture *and* media library selection for photos and videos with the HTML5 input element is it possible to select videos with PhoneGap's camera.getPicture method?


`<input type="file" accept="image/*, video/*" capture="camera" />`


If not, a new camera.getMedia method which allows either media type would be great.


HTML5 file input for photos & videos on iOS6 Mobile Safari

[image: html5 file input]


HTML5 file input multimedia actions on iOS6 Mobile Safari

[image: htm5 file input actions for multimedia]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [navigator.camera.getPicture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameragetpicturesuccesscallback-errorcallback-options) and set the MediaType to VIDEO in the [options parameter](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameramediatype--enum).